# ¿Cómo buscar un elemento de un arreglo que esta dentro de un struct?

Tags: c, struct

me gustaria buscar un elemento que esta dentro de un array que a su vez esta dentro de un struct. Por el momento tengo esto:

```
struct nodo buscarPlataforma(char serie[]){
  for(struct nodo *actual= first; actual != NULL; actual= actual -> next){
      for(int i=0; i<TAM_SERIES; i++){
          if(strcmp(actual->item.series[i], serie) == 0){
              return actual->item.nombre;
          }
      }
  }
}
```

Y estos son los struct:

```
struct Plataforma {
  char nombre[TAM_NOMBRE]; // nombre de la plataforma
  char series[TAM_SERIES][TAM_NOMBRE]; // array de series de la plataforma
  int nTemporadas[TAM_SERIES]; // array que indica el número de temporadas de las series
  int nSeries; // número de series del array series
  int nClientes; // número de clientes de la plataforma
  float presupuesto; // presupuesto en miles de euros de la plataforma
};

struct nodo {
    struct Plataforma item;
    struct nodo *prev, *next;
};
```

Querria retornar el nombre de la plataforma en la que se encuentra la serie, alguna idea?
Gracias

Answer (score 3):

Un nombre se guarda en una cadena de texto. Por lo tanto el tipo de retorno de la función debería ser `char*`. Así:

```
char* buscarPlataforma(char serie[]){
    ...
}
```

Probé el código y con unos cambios menores me funcionó. Puedes verlo tu mismo [aquí](https://tio.run/##fVRta9swEP7uX3FL2UhSJ3W7DgauA9vIoJBmo8lg0IWhynIjZsuaJJeWkT@2r/thmd4c20m2gCPfc/c8utOdjEcPGG@3J5ThvEoJXEmV0nK8ngRtSFD2YLDgJCUZZQSW726@zz/dvL@dwsVlB11Mb6@nC3gTBYF65kR7QPMrrOBzjhTKSlGg1mu8H8XKtLR/cRAcEn8FAHiNhI4o7gW5a/JYxXB25mHQWecI@I5XsyQRlMi7Js/VgQISAj0bARd7TIoyneaSFLwUKEUduZbEz4royJRiBCQH9ud3QURp5NSO6cSl36pWXljLldOwdunkXr9L@pBTwtQhDXv8WB1ZXiIFXBBZ8YpIVVpyywbCoKC5Y5NKlEdkNk2fbOtMh6DdMqrrjS1o/UOt/xjCkJEnFVu26zhRWU6fILECTqQ3ny4/zq6/9kJrOlDDMwQYSWRy4YiT3Pu1Z1FWas2R@NFAM520pAWXJZM9C266cgCXIbwN4Txqe1@75TyKdi/Gb73zL7NZve4qGEJGhVS6gFe@Fu0wQzeE@0piJJoj6TvYNnBg0tBov32GQ4RVhfLEScbgTHiR2C1rO6nx0QTMaQ7qioycGQqqk4livVy1bqa2T08HTfF6fjKzOS543@mNJqZlY39X6Cr0mUKi5TpM8xNEVYJBh@puYdyK3ATNah7PivQEBIHJtUCU9b04158blfV7L@U31gvr0Ri3pAdxNzA9Euiu0X7kEUlf6MVqP5b/P9YGu1b6z05y2Oru/P0jm7qmTbDd/gU).

---

En la realidad hay series que están disponibles en varias plataformas. Eso significa que en ocasiones vas a tener que duplicar la información. Entonces me parece mejor idea crear una estructura `Serie` para las series y que las plataformas guarden un puntero a las series que tienen:

```
struct Serie {
    char nombre[TAM_NOMBRE];
    int nTemporadas;
    int nEpisodios;
    ...
}

struct Plataforma {
    char nombre[TAM_NOMBRE];
    Serie* series[TAM_SERIES];
    int nClientes;
    float presupuesto; 
};

struct Nodo {
    struct Plataforma item;
    struct Nodo *prev, *next;
};
```

Se me ocurre que puedes almacenar las series por un lado y las plataformas por otro. Te dejo la tarea de decidir si será mediante listas enlazadas o reservar una buena porción de memoria contigua que puedas tratar como arreglo. 1 MB no es una cantidad nada despreciable. La estructura de ejemplo ocupa unos 10 bytes. Así que **1 MB / 10 bytes = 104857** series.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, ya habia hecho ese cambio que me lo habia comentado otro compañero pero estaba declarando la funcion debajo del main :) Gracias por tu tiempo